# Python - Multiple Plots in a Single Figure - Loop in DIfferent columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot in a single image, multiple columns of a table.

The idea is to optimize the process with a loop.

It is important to note that all the columns share the same y-axis, and that the x scale varies for each column.

The Final result should look something like this:

[image]

I've already tried some things, but with no success, in my code I'm creating several figures, only plotting in the first graph:

```
def facies_plot_all(logs):
    logs = sort_values(by='y')
    ztop=logs.Y.min(); zbot=logs.Y.max()
    
    for col in logs.columns:
        numcol = (logs.shape[1])
        f, ax = plt.subplots (nrows=1, ncols=numcol, figsize (20,25))
        ax[x+1].plot(logs[col],logs.Y,'-')
```

I'm relatively new to programming and still searching for a way to solve this issue.
Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `subplots` outside of `for` loop:

```
logs = sort_values(by='y')
ztop=logs.Y.min(); zbot=logs.Y.max()

numcol = (logs.shape[1])
f, axes es= plt.subplots (nrows=1, ncols=numcol, 
                        sharey=True,
                        figsize=(20,25))

for (ax, col) in zip(axes,logs.columns):
    ax.plot(logs[col],logs.Y,'-')
```